# Tracking from httpd instance to PHP script when PHP is a module

Tags: php, performance, apache-httpd

I'm trying to figure out exactly what's going on that kicks CPU usage in random `httpd` workers so high but I'm having a little hard of a time figuring out what PHP page is being requested so that I can try to figure out why it's chewing up CPU. If PHP were done as regular (as opposed to Fast) CGI I could look at the process list, but we're using mod_php.

Is there a way to get PHP 5.3 to report performance statistics for currently running scripts? This may also be relevant if we decide to eventually go the `php-fpm` route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable `mod_status` and turn on `ExtendedStatus`, it will display the request being handled by each worker.

Comment: This is exactly what I was needing, ty.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I am not sure if you can do that with normal php but you can use php-fpm to show you a status page
in this link you can see how to do it:
https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/php/fpm-status-page/

Second you can enable slowlog in php-fpm with this you can see which script are running so slowly.
here's an exaple to how to do it:
https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/php/fpm-slow-log/